# Determine application directory of Catalyst application running under mod_perl

Tags: perl, catalyst, mod-perl

When running under mod_perl Cwd's `getcwd` returns `/`
When using Mojolicious, I can simply put `$self->app->home` in any controller to determine the absolute path to the base directory in which the application runs.

Is there something similar in Catalyst?

Regards,
ldx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catalyst has `$c->path_to( 'something' )`, so you can directly ask it to give you a path to a file or resource.

Alternatively, you could use `$c->config->{ home }` to get your root directory. But that seems a bit hackish and is not guaranteed to work with the next release of Catalyst.

Comment: There's two things that I want to do: 1) find a resource: that should work with $c->path_to => ok 2) Find out if a directory is writable. should work with $c->config->{home} but indeed, not guaranteed to work with the next release of Catalyst. Any ideas how I could do that?